# Bundler: find which gem depends on this?

Tags: ruby, dependencies, rubygems, bundler, dependency-management

The backports library is installed when I run `bundle install` but I don't know which gem requires this - is there a way to get bundler to tell me this, or is there some other way to find this out?

I need it to be some other way than `bundle viz` as I get errors on running that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try looking inside your Gemfile.lock file. 
Dependencies are nested underneath what they are required by.

Answer (score 2):

You should check `Gemfile.lock`. As a shortcut, just do <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> & search for *backports* in that file.

Comment: Thanks Gaurish, Adam just beat you to it! :-) +1

Comment: No Problem lain, you got your answer. that's what more important :)